# change color for second column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery responsive table.
When you reduce the browser window you can see a different lay out.

I want to change the color of second column values of each table but I don't know how to give ids for second column values and change its color.

Providing a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/37/) and also my code below:

```
#page-wrap {
    margin: 50px;
}
/* 
        Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
        */
 table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
th {
    background: #1a4567;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
td, th {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
}
/* 
        Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
        This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
        and also iPads specifically.
        */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    tr {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }
    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: static;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    /*
            Label the data
            */
    td:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content:"BOM Id";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(2):before {
        content:"Brand Name";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before {
        content:"BOM Type";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before {
        content:"BOM Description";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before {
        content:"Edit";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before {
        content:"Related";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(7):before {
        content:"Print";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(8):before {
        content:"ECO";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(9):before {
        content:"Dev";
    }
    td:nth-of-type(10):before {
        content:"Files";
    }
}
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 320px;
    }
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        width: 495px;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html this should help

Comment: What is purpose of posting not working jsfiddle?

Comment: The php code is second column then I think this should help you `td:nth-child(2n+2) { background:#222; }` in case you have more than two columns. OR you can use `even` or `odd` in place of `2n+2` as you required.

Comment: @crazyrohila: thanks for your reply. I am talking with respect to iphone lay out second column

Comment: @user2045025: Not sure what you mean by that. Are you saying on the iPhone your table doesn't render as a table with th and tr, td elements? How does it differ? Does `td:nth-child(2) {...}` not work on the iPhone?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I have added an image can u chk it

Comment: @roasted Isn't the point to show what he's tried, and give the answerers a chance to try to fix it without having to build their own entire fiddles?

Comment: @ErikE I would say what is the purpose to just paste code without making any effort to set correctly a jsfiddle. I mean put javascript code in javascript field at least. BTW, it's not the first time this user is doing this. Just my personal opinion

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction, @roasted. Obviously I didn't actually click on the link. My mistake. Now I know what you mean by a "not working jsfiddle"--one that doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to color the second column you can use something similar to:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    background: #CCC
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu25W/) - Change color of second column

---

If you also want to include the header itself you can add the same to the `th`, similar to:

```
th:nth-child(2) {
    background: teal
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUJZB/) - Change color of Second Column Header too

---

If you want to color every second column and not just the second column you can use odd and even similar to this:

```
th:nth-child(even) {
    background: teal;
}

td:nth-child(even) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKa5V/) - Apply colors to every second column

---

Comment: @Franois: thanks for your reply...i was talking with respect to second column in iphone lay out....

Answer (score 1):

For only the 2nd colum of every table you can

```
td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2){}
```

or

```
td:first-child+td,th:first-child+th{}
```

to make sure if works in early IE

Comment: thanks for your reply...i was talking with respect to second column in iphone lay out...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proper [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQNE7/) for your request. I've cleaned it up and added two rows in the **CSS**.

---

You mentionned you didn't know how to give *ID*'s to second columns for smaller resolution devices. For your example, the *selector* for the first column is `td:before` and for the second column is `td`. More specifically the following CSS seems to accomplish what you were looking for :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
   td {
      color:orange;
   }

   td:before {
      color:darkblue; 
   }
}
```

From your responsive transformations, your first column is actually from the content **CSS** *attribute* on `td:before` and not the `th` markup anymore. This is wrong from a semantic point of view, but I'm guessing you have restrictions forcing this behaviour.

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question! :-)